# Склонение Келяускас Эдгарас Викторо

Tags: склонение

Склонение Келяускас Эдгарас Викторо

Comment: Вообще-то, Вы бы повежливее как-то написали. Хотя бы — "Подскажите, пожалуйста, как склоняется ...?"

Answer (score 3):

Как я понимаю, это имя мужчины. Значит, склоняться будут два первых слова, а "Викторо" склоняться не будет: Келяускаса Эдрараса Викторо и т.д.

Comment: "Келяускас" - скорее всего фамилия.
"Эдрарас Викторо" - имя, причем я не уверен, что от последнего слова не "отпали" последние буквы.  
Остальное - согласен.